# How to set no of rows in gridview?That would be fixed.Like i want 2 rows and 3 columns .So,is it possible with gridview?

Tags: android, android-studio, gridview

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <GridView
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:id="@+id/gridview"
     android:numColumns="2"
     android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
     android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
     android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
/>
```

**Here i add no of columns.
Can i add no of rows in gridview?**

Comment: you can set either of one. And other part is dynamic. Means whatever itemList you pass to grid view it will expand to that length.

Answer (score 0):

set `android:numColumns="3"` and set no of rows programatically in adapter like:
inside `getView()`

```
if(position < 2){
    // do your task
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't make any sense to fix number of rows in gridview. But if you want 3 columns and 2 rows only then you should use **android:numColumns="3"** in xml file and you have to make sure that number of items in adapter should be 6. If number of items increases gridview automatically add more rows.

Comment: I was wondering to set a ui like that.It has 3 items only.I can do that in relative layout or linear layout by using button but i was trying to do it with gridview . So thats why i wanted to know that is it possible or not.

Comment: Can you suggest anything that would be helpful for me?